# Comparing the big-O and big-Omega of functions

Tags: time-complexity

I can find the big-O and big-Omega of functions but it is hard for me to check if a certain function is the big-O or big-Omega of another one. for example:

Is `n^(1/2)` the big-O or big-Omega of `n^(2/3)`?
Is `log(5n)` the big-O or big-Omega of `10log(n)`?

I'm unsure how to compare them beyond just using a graphing calculator. Can someone direct me to a resource that provides techniques on comparing the growths of functions?

Answer (score 1):

First one is trivial, you just compare the powers, so `a = n^(1/2)` <= `b = n^(2/3)`. Therefore you `a` is in `O(n^(2/3))` and analog `b` is in `Omega(n^(1/2))`.

For the second, you need the logarithm rules, which give you

```
log(5n) = log(5) + log(n)

//Since log(5) is constant
log(n) < 10log(n) //wait, 10 also

==> asymptotic equally growing, both in Theta
```

As a check-up tool, you can take a look at [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=57ad04c0f04cc92e742205985c18023e).

You can also use the limit of their quotient for `n` to infinity when the function are more complex to check it. For example to see for `n!` and `n^n`.

A quick [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities) for most common functions.

Hope it helps!

Comment: _"`a` is in `O(n^(2/3))`"_ is technically correct, but this is not the upper bound one would use for this (not a tight bound). Rather, `n^(1/2)` is in `O(n^(1/2))`. However your other statement, _"`b` is in `O(n^(1/2))`"_ is not correct. `const*n^(1/2)` is not an asymptotic upper bound on `b=n^(2/3)`.